# Do I need to call SelectObject() to restore a object retreived with GetStockObject()?

Tags: winapi, mfc, gdi

I'm using MFC...

When I create a new brush, I know I need to restore the old bush using SelectObject:

```
CBrush brushFill;
brushFill.CreateSolidBrush(colorFill);
CBrush *oldBrush = pDC->SelectObject(&brushFill);
// Draw something here.
pDC->SelectObject(oldBrush);
```

However, if I get the brush using GetStockObject(), do I need to to restore it, too?

```
CBrush *oldBrush = (CBrush *)pDC->SelectObject(GetStockObject(HOLLOW_BRUSH));
// Draw something here.
pDC->SelectObject(oldBrush);
```

I ask, because that code occasionally crashes. I'm unsure if that's due to me not supposed to save/restore stock items, or my typecast to a CBrush*. If the latter, I'm thinking I should save/restore an HGDIOBJ handle:

```
HGDIOBJ oldBrush = pDC->SelectObject(GetStockObject(HOLLOW_BRUSH));
// Draw something here.
pDC->SelectObject(oldBrush);
```

If the former, I wouldn't save/restore the previous object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should *always* 'bracket' any operations on a device context with the [`SaveDC()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdc-class?view=vs-2019#savedc) and [`RestoreDC()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdc-class?view=vs-2019#restoredc) member functions of the `CDC` object:

```cpp
int DCsave = pDC->SaveDC(); // Saves all (or most) settings and object selections
// ... Do your drawing operations, etc.
pDC->RestoreDC(DCsave);     // Restores the saved state and all selected objects
```

Also, just for info, you may find the [`SelectStockObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cdc-class?view=vs-2019#selectstockobject) member a bit easier to use:

```cpp
pDC->SelectStockObject(HOLLOW_BRUSH);
```

Note (from the comment made by [IInspectable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889329/iinspectable)): Although deselection of the GDI 'Stock Objects' may *seem* unnecessary (after all, there will be several of these selected by default), other code may be relying on having the previous object (brush, in your case) selected; failure to restore this selection can thus cause that code to fail in ways that are near impossible to track down.

Comment: Dangerous advice there. There's two objects involved in every `SelectObject` call: The object currently selected into a device context, and the object about to be selected. It's *always* required to restore a device context to the state in which it was handed to you, just before passing it back. Other code will make assumptions about ownership and lifetimes of objects selected into this device context. Failure to restore a device context will cause perfectly valid code to fail.

Comment: @IInspectable Good point - and one that I can't (and won't) argue with!! I have edited my answer to reflect the **need** (rather than mere *preference*) to save/restore the device context. I hope you approve.

Comment: That conveys a much more concise statement. I'm curious, though, what does the *"(or most)"* portion of the comment refer to? Are there client-controlled resources that `SaveDC`/`RestoreDC` doesn't account for?

Comment: @IInspectable Well, not so much *resources* but, for example, does the current position (as used by `MoveTo(x,y)`) get saved? I don't know, TBO, which is why I added "most."